# Set border width and color in Mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, geojson, web-mapping, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm working on an application based on Mapbox GL, I need to give to the user the opportunity to set the width and the color of the borders of polygons but I can't find the right GeoJSON proprieties to accomplish it. There's a way acting directly on polygon's GeoJSON or I need to create a whole new layer just to draw and customize the polygon's border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a layer of [type: fill](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-fill):

Border color could be set with the paint property [`fill-outline-color`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#paint-fill-fill-outline-color).

For the border width you'll need to use an additional layer, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351902/in-a-mapbox-gl-js-layer-of-type-fill-can-we-control-the-stroke-thickness/50372832#50372832

Answer (score 0):

In the fill mode, you can't set the width.
If you want to accomplish that, you will need to create a line mode layer after the fill mode layer with the same source. Example here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/

Answer (score 0):

(2016) Border width is not possible because of WebGL technical limitations. Add another layer for the outline.

src: [github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3018)